# How to I fetch rows from one table via linked tables in Yii?

Tags: yii

The programmer who was working for the company I used has quit, so I'm stuck with learning Yii myself. I think the solution for this is easy if you know Yii, but for me it's not so obvious.

I have three tables:

```
| Store | Brand | link_store_brand |
|-------|-------|------------------|
| id    | id    | storeID          |
|       |       | brandID          |
```

Now I need to fetch all brands that is associated with store

I have this code in my Store model:

```
public function relations()
{
     return array(
        'brands' => array(CActiveRecord::MANY_MANY,
            'Brand',
            'link_store_brand(storeID, brandID)',
            'order' => 'brands.rank DESC, brands.name ASC',
            'with' => 'logo'),
     );
}
```

So in my controller I do this:

```
    $store          = Store::model()->findByPk($requestData->id);
    $brands         = $store->getBrands();
```

I know I can do `Store::model()->with('brands')->findByPk()`. But a field naming issue makes the SQL query fail. So I'm first retrieving the store data, then fetching the brands.

But `$store->getBrands()` is not working (SQL fails) so I think I have to use query builder and make my own query to fetch brands. But how do I do that?

Comment: What is the exact error why does SQL fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define two `Many To Many` relationship between `Store`, `Brand`, `link_store_brand` in this way:

`Store:`

```
public function relations()
{

    return array(
        'link_store_brand' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'LinkStoreBrand', 'store_id'),
    );
}
```

`Brand:`

```
public function relations()
{

    return array(
        'link_store_brand' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'LinkStoreBrand', 'brand_id'),
    );
}
```

`LinkStoreBrand:`

```
 public function relations()
{

    return array(
        'store' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Store', 'store_id'),
        'brand' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Brand', 'brand_id'),
    );
}
```

Now, If you want to access all brands of an store, you can do this:

```
$links = LinkStoreBrand::model()->with("brand")->find("store_id = :store_id", array(":store_id"=>$requestData->id));
//$links will be an array
$brands = array();
foreach($links as $link)
{
   array_push($brands, $link->brand);
}
```

Now, `$brands` is an array of brands that associated with an store.

**Note:** You must generate `LinkStoreBrand` model from `link_store_brand` table if you did not generated it already.